# C++ Use template class to call non static member function

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I am trying to use a template class as a work around for callback. I want to use a non-static member function for callbacks.

I created two classes:

```
//First Class
class AbstractAction
{
public:
  AbstractAction() = default;
  virtual ~AbstractAction() = 0;

  virtual void exec() = 0;
};

//Second class
template<class T>
class Action: public AbstractAction
{
public:

  Action<T>(T* obj, void (T::*func)())
  : class_obj_(obj), class_func_(func) {}

  virtual void exec() {class_obj_->*class_func_;}

private:
  T * class_obj_;
  void (T::*class_func_)();

};
```

In my Code I have a class called "Button". This class has a member of `AbstractAction`. When the Button is pressed it calls the `exec()` function. `exec()` is virtual so actually the function of `Action<SomeClass>` is called.

Now I create a class using an Object of `Action`

```
class HardWork
{
public:
  HardWork()
  : action(this, &HardWork::workOnAction)  {}

private:
  void workOnAction() { /* do something using non static variables */ };

  Action<HardWork> action;
};
```

And the compile says:

```
In instantiation of 'void display::Action<T>::exec() [with T = HardWork]':
error: invalid use of non-static member function of type 'void (HardWork::)()'
   virtual void exec() {class_obj_->*class_func_;}
                        ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Why does he complain about this? He has a pointer to an actual object of `Hardwork` so he should know what to call. Second and more important what way around do I have. I don't want to use the static work around. What options do I have?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a reproducible example, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You forgot to actually call: `class_obj_->*class_func_` -> `(class_obj_->*class_func_)()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
class_obj_->*class_func_;
```

you dereference the function pointer but you don't actually do anything with it.  You still need to call the fuction like you normally would.  You do need to add some extra parentheses to do this though and that would look like

```
virtual void exec() { (class_obj_->*class_func_)();}
                      ^^^^^get function^^^^^^^^^ ^
                                                 | call function
```

Comment: I found it in the net withtout parentheses. I tried it with parentheses at the end but not both. No it is working. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid messy syntax of calling through a member function pointer, [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) can be used since C++17:

```
virtual void exec() {
    std::invoke(class_func_, class_obj_);
}
```